# How to get perfect round figure count in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5, sql-query-store

In my Postgresql database, the `Student` table has `student_marks` and `total_marks` columns.

I want to get the percentage based on student marks.

For example:

```
student_marks * 100 / total_marks => 118 * 100 / 147 = 80.27 = 80%
```

If the first two digits of decimal number are below 50, ex: 75.49 then it should be 75% or if the first two digits of decimal number are equal to 50 or above 50, ex: 67.50 or 67.52 then it should be 68%
so

This query works for me:

```
select TO_CHAR(19.57, 'fm99%') as abc;
```

it returns 20%.

The problem is of the student get 100% marks:

```
select TO_CHAR(100, 'fm99%') as abc;
```

returns `##%`

Please show me a solution for this or else suggest another way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Use ROUND() function: example:   SELECT ROUND(80.27), ROUND(80.55)

Comment: Or, use longer format string in your query ( adding one more 9 to the format string ) if you have to have the % sign.    SELECT TO_CHAR(100, 'fm999%'), TO_CHAR(ROUND(80.55), 'fm999%')

Comment: the reason you get `##%` is because you have asked for 2 digit display (`'fm99%'`) but you need 3 digits to cater for 100 so as mentioned above you can use `'fm999%'`  and/or `ROUND()`

Comment: @PaulMaxwell  select TO_CHAR(29*100/147, 'fm999%') as abc ; ---> in this query 29*100/147 is 19 but I want 2 decimal points after 19 , ex: 19.72. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: select TO_CHAR(29*100/147 :: numeric, 'fm999%') as abc ;  ---> this query gives me perfect round figure. thank You.

Comment: for 2 decimal places the format needs to include positions for the seperator and the extra two digits, so `select TO_CHAR(29*100/147 :: numeric, 'fm999.99%') as abc ; `